# How to add 15 minutes to date stored as string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried multiple ways but nothing seems to work.

I have datetime in this format **1.1.2021 10:10** and I would like to add 15 minutes to it so it would look like this **1.1.2021 10:25**.

Date time is stored in cell as string and this is what I tried 
`akt.Offset(0,2) + TimeSerial(0, 15, 0)` 
`DateAdd("n", 15, akt.Offset(0,2))`
The result is always blank

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to do it?

Comment: On a properly parsed date, you would get a result, not a blank. On a date that cannot be parsed, you would get a type mismatch. If you are not getting either, either this code does not run, or you should remove that `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: The real question is why are you storing date/times as strings and not serial numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *CDate*:

```vb
' True date value:
=DateAdd("n", 15, CDate(Replace(akt.Offset(0,2), ".", "/")))

' Text date:
=Format(DateAdd("n", 15, CDate(Replace(akt.Offset(0,2), ".", "/"))), "d.m.yyyy hh:nn")
```